# Parallel compilation : does --jobs works?

Tags: ros, rosmake, parallel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a debian installation of Diamondback and I did not succeed usung parallel compilation.
I may build 2 packages at the same time using --threads, but when only building one package I can't ask it to build in parallel the exe. If I go into my package I can run make -j3 without any problem and it works.

Is it an issue in my CMakeLists or a rosmake issue ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9598/parallel-compilation-:-does---jobs-works-?/) by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 352 on 2011-03-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is working :
**export ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS=-j3**

but there is no way to make the --pjobs working. I have enougth with the former.

---

Originally posted by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) with karma: 352 on 2011-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-04-17**:
This is the actual correct answer. rosmake --pjobs=4 or --threads=4 doesn't work for me either. Neither does export ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS=-l3 (-l instead of -j) as mentioned at http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you are talking about --pjobs.  It does work.

It simply overrides the ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS environment setting.  If you are using a package with just a Makefile you will have to pass it through in that Makefile.  For example the [kdl Makefile](https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry/file/5f6c08ac82ee/kdl/Makefile) does this.

If you use mk/cmake.mk, as the default Makefile does, it also uses ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS when executing the Makefile generated by cmake.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) on 2011-03-29**:
If the kdl Makefile would have used `${MAKE}` instead of `make`, the extra `ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS` in its makefile wouldn't have been necessary, right?

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-03-29**:
the kdl example helped. It thougth this was done automatically. So my projects with Makefile are now working with parallel build, and I think the cmakes one also. Thanks both !